# .htaccess and local multi domains

Tags: php, .htaccess

Need a litlle help with htaccess file. I have a local site `http://foo.bar`, wich works with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value. In the root of site exist .htaccess file with rules

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

The document root of that site is the same for `http://localhost/foo`. When I open `http://localhost/foo/user/login`, I get 404 error. That same link perfectly works with `http://foo.bar/user/login` and `http://localhost/foo/index.php/user/login`

What I need to wrote in .htaccess file for currect working on localhost/foo url site without index.php in url?

Comment: Try checking out your apache error logs to see what file apache is trying to map that request to that doesn't exist.

Comment: Try setting RewriteBase accordingly. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase